# Get random records in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql table, `Employee` which has 4 columns.

- Id
- Name
- Address
- Status – Fixed Type (Enum). Having 3 fixed values – `OPEN`, `CLOSED` and `PENDING`.

Let’s assume **Total Records** in the table are 200.

Now, I want to form a query which would return -

- 50 random records which have status “OPEN”.
- 25 random records which have status “CLOSED”.
- 45 random records which have status “PENDING”.

I have tried with the one fragmented query and it worked fine but looking for single query solution for whole scenario.

```
Select * from Employee a where a.Status = 'OPEN' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50
Select * from Employee a where a.Status = 'CLOSED' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25
Select * from Employee a where a.Status = 'PENDING' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 45
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you have tried? What will happen if everyone starts asking for solutions of their daily job/school tasks ? :)

Comment: I have tries this by three different queries and its working fine, but I am trying to form a single query for this IS IT POSSIBLE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Union` to combine multiple queries and remember to assign alias for each sub/parent query.

```
select * from ((Select * from Employee a where a.Status = 'OPEN' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50) 
union 
(Select * from Employee b where b.Status = 'CLOSED' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25) 
union 
(Select * from Employee c where c.Status = 'PENDING' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 45)) d;
```

I hope this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need it as a single query (mildly painful) or as 3 separate queries?

As 3 separate queries, the simplest option would be something like

```
Select * from Employee where Status = 'OPEN' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50;
Select * from Employee where Status = 'CLOSED' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25;
Select * from Employee where Status = 'PENDING' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 45;
```

Comment: Can you suggest a single query for this. Three different queries requires 3 different executions which is a very costly database operation.